# Why is my decimal to binary program returning the value backwards and in a table format?

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters, data-conversion

I'm using python 3.5.2 to make this program. It'supposed to take any decimal number and convert it to binary.

```
number = int(input('Enter a number in base 10: '))
base2 = ''
while(number > 0):
     rem = number % 2
     number = number // 2
     base2 = srt(number) + str(rem)
     print(rem)
#This was to prevent the end text from sticking to the print
input('\nEnter to end')
```

It returns the correct values, but backwards and in a column and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some modifications to your code:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number in base 10: '))
base2 = ''
while(number > 0):
    rem = number % 2
    number = number // 2 # can be number //= 2, or number >>= 1 
    base2 += str(rem)
    #print(rem) # no need to print
print(base2[::-1])
```

Or more simple:

```
base2 = bin(number)[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints the lowest bit of remaining number on separate lines so that's why you see them in reverse order. You could change your code to store bits to an array and then after the loop print them in reverse order:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number in base 10: '))
base2 = []
while(number > 0):
     base2.append(str(number % 2))
     number = number // 2

print(''.join(reversed(base2)))
```

Python also has built-in method [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#bin) than can do the conversion for you:

```
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
```

Comment: I would use the 'bin(i)', but I'm using this in a binary calculator and sadly it doesn't work the way it I need it to.

Comment: @TylerSeward Is there any specific reason why `bin` doesn't work?

Comment: After I had the program do what ever arithmetic operator it needs to do, I take it that variable and plug it into bin, but it didn't return anything value or error.

Comment: @TylerSeward That's interesting, for me `bin` either returns a string or an error depending on the input. Maybe you could print the value of the variable just before you pass it to `bin` to make sure that it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Sorry edit to that. It prints back a base 10. Essentially the bin doesn't do anything.

Comment: @TylerSeward Would it be possible to edit the question to show how you call `bin` and the result it returns?